# AC analysis of SMPS shows instability. How to modify the analysis to reflect the transient stability?

Tags: ltspice, control-system, stability, small-signal, compensation

### Background

I have designed a switch-mode power stage with voltage-mode control that uses an LCLC filter in its output to obtain a very low ripple output voltage.

I have empirically arrived at a compensation network that makes its control stable and provides a satisfying bandwith. I now want to carry out a proper small-signal stability analysis with this stable configuration as a starting point. The reason is that different values for the L and C can make it unstable again, so I want to simulate quickly how to adjust the compensation network.

For this I have replaced the comparator with an op-amp and abstracted all the feedback paths as voltage sources (`E1` and `E2`). The signal `phout1` is the voltage after the first LC and `out1` is the voltage after the second LC. The signal input is provided by `V6` (also has a 2.5 VDC bias). This works very well to reproduce the transient behavior of the actual switch-mode circuit.

[image]

### Question

I am interested in the gain and phase vs. frequency Bode plots, in a way **that takes into account the lowpassing effect that appears when feeding the setpoint from `V6` and `R5`**.

### Attempts

Below is shown what I tried. I found out that this method is equivalent to the so called "Middlebrook" method, i.e. it gives identical results. The examples by LTspice itself (e.g. `Loopgain2.asc`) also produce equivalent results.

I cut the AC feedback to the noninverting input and AC-ground it instead. Then I feed an `AC 1` source into one of the op-amp inputs and monitor what arrives on the other end of the cut.

This is shown below. It produces a result that indicates that phase drops to 0 at about 2 kHz with 80 dB of gain left. The transient is fully stable in this case with `Rfb=1Meg`, but the input signal is also heavily low-passed, so maybe this is what makes it look stable. Does the low-pass simply prevent the destabilizing frequencies from ever occuring on the feedback node?

I tested the latter, by injecting my transient signal into `V3` instead of `V6`. And indeed, it is now oscillating at frequencies that make sense in the context of the loop gain analysis.

That means, that the open-loop gain is correctly measured, but it doesn't take into account the stabilizing lowpass that signals experience when fed from `V6` and `R5`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Question has been significantly updated. Earlier comments are now obsolete, but can be seen in [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142645/discussion-between-tobalt-and-ernestog). [Edited by a moderator to clarify the contents of the chatroom.]

Comment: @tobalt, I have difficulty to understand your model. What is the topology for the power stage, I think you did not disclose it. Then, why don't you use an averaged model, mine were ported to LTspice long ago and they toggle between CCM and DCM. Finally, you could give a try to my free SIMPLIS [templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf), they are easy to tweak for reflecting your particular configuration.

Comment: @VerbalKint The output stage is a simple synchronous buck, i.e. CCM always. It switches at approx. 1 MHz. Not sure what an averaged model is.. Isn't mine one ?

Comment: @tobalt, you can have a look at my [APEC 2019](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202019.pdf) seminar dedicated to the buck converter. There is modeling in the slides. Average models are described in my [APEC 2013](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202013.pdf) sem for instance.

Comment: @VerbalKint 1) after scrolling over your 2013 material I am rather positive that I employ an average model. My voltage waveforms follow the one from the switching circuit but lack the spectral content that the switching frequency brings about. 2) My buck isn't usual in two regards: It has LCLC output filtering, so twice the phase shift. And I don't have a dedicated error amp, but feed all signals directly into the comparator which performs error feedback and PWM all in one. So I am uncertain if the standard buck course material is relevant.

Comment: U1 is a comparator? ...Then why does it have negative feedback? With a comparator, you must have poles in the RHP, otherwise it doesn't oscillate (switch); lower poles/zeroes I'm not sure about (can you meaningfully average over the oscillations, continuing the small-signal analysis?).  I suppose @VerbalKint knows this better than I do, heh. For my part, I strongly encourage a current-mode design, and, voltage feedback to the first filter node (one LC in) is approximately suitable for the purpose. The filter also doesn't need to be designed whole, it can be in parts.

Comment: @TimWilliams Please refer to the Background section above. It is a comparator in the switching circuit. And yes it has negative feedback to perform error cancellation (but also positive feedback). When turning it into the average model, it is replaced with an opamp. I removed the positive feedback in the process, because it was Ac coupled, and when removing the switching frequency from it, all that was left was the constant DC bias. I just checked, but adding the pos. feedback back in, changes nothing.

Comment: @tobalt, then, for the reason you exposed - it differs from a classical structure - I would run a SIMPLIS cycle-by-cycle simulation and obtain the ac response immediately, without resorting to an intermediate model.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but LTspice released a new milestone version (17.1.x) within the past month which includes a new `.fra` directive to be used with the new `FRA` symbol to do these types of analyses directly.

Comment: @SteKulov indeed missed/forgot this comment.. Do you wanna convert it to an answer ? It pretty much solves this issue..There are two negative feedback paths (one DC+AC, one only AC) So I might have to experiment a bit.. If you have a suggestion in this regard, it would be welcome, too.

Comment: @tobalt  Haha, no worries.  Nah, I'm not confident in my SMPS feedback loop abilities.  I just know this feature exists.  I have never used it before (I still run the older LTspice version).  Perhaps it's best to post your own answer after you experiment with it a bit yourself?